# Home and a List page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What i want to do is pass from my home application to a list. I have the list and my home on different .js files, but now, how can i show first my home, and then, with one click, send to the list?

My files, next. First the home code and view:

home-component.js

```
(function(){
     'use strict';
    var home = {
        templateUrl: './app/components/list-component/home-component/home.html',
        controller: homeCtrl
    };

    angular
    .module('payApp')
    .component('home', home);

    function homeCtrl(){

        var home = this;
    }  

    })();
```

home.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="title">
                            <h3><strong>¡Welcome!</strong></h3>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="">Start</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, my list files.

payment-component.js

```
(function(){
     'use strict';
    var pays = {
        templateUrl: './app/components/list-component/paymentcompo.html',
        controller: payCtrl
    };

    angular
    .module('payApp')
    .component('payInvoice', pays);
    payCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];
    function payCtrl($scope){

}
})();
```

It's html view:

paymentcompo.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Payment Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Tax Id</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="pool" ng-repeat="info in list | filter: search">
                <th>{{info.Id}}</th>
                <th>{{info.name}}</th>
                <th>{{info.taxId}}</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And, in the end, my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="payApp">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pay This</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="app/componentes/css/pay-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<head>


</head>

<body>

<pay-Invoice></pay-Invoice>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/payapp.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/list-component/payment-component.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/list-component/home-component/home-component.js"></script>
<script src="app/factory/pay-factories.js"></script>
<script src="app/routes/routes.js">

</body>
</html>
```

I'd read that i need also use ngRoute, so i added and create my `routes.js`.

**EDITED**

This is my routes.js code:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('payApp')
        .config(config);


    config.$inject = ["$routeProvider","$locationProvider"];
        function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

            $routeProvider
                .when('/home',{
                    template: '<home></home>',
                })

                .when('/listado',{
                    template: '<pay-invoice></pay-invoice>',
                })

                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/home',
                });

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        }

        })();
```

I need to pass two things:

1. The home view, because is the very first thing i need to show.
2. The list view, which will be triggered by the button on the home view.

How can i do that? What other thing i need to do on the index.html? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `angular-route` you need to create container div in your main html file.

So instead of

```
<pay-Invoice></pay-Invoice>
```

in your index html file place a container component:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

This will tell `ngRoute` that it should mount route components to this container and swich it when location changes
More about it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: I've just did it, and now, everything turns in blank... I just need the ng-view?

Comment: Here is an example on how to do that properly: https://jsfiddle.net/danielclasen/m729ru7w/